# Tekmar 532 gives error code about voltage too low. Hooked up to 24v powersupply, fluke multi-meter reads 24.18v across wire

Tags: thermostat, power-supply

I have a tekmar 532 which I have hooked up to a Signcomplex 24V 2A 48W Power Supply Adapter Transformers 24VDC LED Driver Switching Power Supply for LED Strip Light AC/DC Power Adaptor, UL Listed.

https://www.amazon.ca/gp/product/B079BJS3F4/ref=ppx_yo_dt_b_asin_title_o06_s00?ie=UTF8&psc=1

The tekmar shows an error code POWR which according to the manual means that it is getting insufficient voltage.  I used my fluke multimeter on dc volts across the wires in the wire block of the thermostat and they read 24.18v.  The tekmar 532 claims it need 24v +- 10%.  I tried the other tekmar 532 front on the wiring harness and it says the same thing.

Could the power supply that I bought somehow be at fault?  I only bought this to test out the thermostats.

[image: power supply]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's a DC power supply.  Your Tecmar unit need a 24 volt AC power supply.

You're supposed to use a common-as-dirt, run-of-the-mill 24 volt AC HVAC transformer, which are typically 40 VA in capacity (1-2/3 amps). They go for about $13 at your home supply or HVAC supply house, and they are designed for permanent installation in knockouts or as a substitute for the lid of a junction box.

Using HVAC equipment ...with... HVAC equipment, makes a certain amount of sense, yes?

Anytime you're working in house electrical, there is *always* a better answer than buying random crud off of Amazon.

Answer (score 1):

Looking at this again it seems like the thermostat wants 24v ac so I need a different power supply.

Comment: Yeah, 24VAC/40VA transformers should be pretty trivial to find

Answer (score 1):

Some power supplies have a large amount of dc ripple or don’t work with inductive loads.

I am not sure about your tekmar unit it may be heavily inductive and that will cause the voltage to dive on a switching type supply, or a unit that is sensitive to the ripple.

You can test the ripple if you put the meter on ac volts and measure the supply this value should only be a couple of tenths of a volt defiantly less than .3 or .4 vac. (It won’t harm the meter auto ranging meters like the fluke T series 500 or 600 pick the largest voltage).
The other thing to try is measure the voltage with the load attached if it is an inductive load and a switching supply it may not be large enough.
I have seen supply’s that had 2.5x the current capability fail on inductive loads.

There is a chance that the tekmar unit is faulty but 2 of them? So verification of the voltage under load may be your best next step to see what the problem is.
Note my example is a computer system that draws ~8 amps did not work with a 20 amp switching supply, change to old school transformer and full wave bridge with a cap at 10 amps and it works fine.